# Find matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = -I$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to solve for matrix $A$ where $A^2 = - I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of the same order as $A$. Also, my second question: is there a matrix $A$ where $A^3 = 0$, but $A^2 \neq 0$?
Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Can you create something out of the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sometimes thinking geometrically can help - for the first, think about rotations. For the second think what has to be true about subspaces annihilated by $A$ and $A^2$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $iI$?

For the second, a nilpotent matrix like $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What's the square of $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$?

What are $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^3$?